# nuxtjs: global custome directive doesn't get resolved via plugins array

Tags: directive, nuxt.js

I want to write a directive in nuxts.js and want to add it via the plugins array in the nuxt.config file, but then my directive doesn't get resolved...

```
//plugins/myGlobalDirective.js
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.directive('my-global-directive', {
  inserted: function(el) {
    console.log('my-global-directive')
  }
})

//nuxt.config.js
plugins: [
  '~plugins/myGlobalDirective.js'
],

//component
<template>
  <p v-my-global-directive>lala</p>
</template>
```

that doesn't work.

But if I import it directly in the component it works ( I can also remove it from the plugins array)

```
//component
<template>
  <p v-my-global-directive>lala</p>
</template>
<script>
  import '~/plugins/myGlobalDirective.js'
</script>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**Problem solved**
I have to restart the server if I change something in the nuxt.config file...
And it works with or without the the '/'

Comment: You're missing the '/' in front of plugins/myGlobalDirective.js

Comment: shame on me if that was the mistake... I will check it in the evening when I'm home again ;)